# Is it possible to use AWS Cloudfront as an IP address location service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, geolocation, ip, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to send Cloudfront a header to have it look up the IP address in their database, rather than the IP address of the client?

For example, if a server wants to determine location based on an IP address, it could set an `x-real-ip` and `x-forwarded-for` which Cloudfront would then use for the IP to location look up.

As it stands, I've tried to add the following headers with no luck.

```golang
    r.Header.Set("x-real-ip", user-ip)
    r.Header.Set("x-forwarded-proto", user-ip)
    r.Header.Set("x-forwarded-for", user-ip)
```

I then create a Cloudfront distribution that forwards `CloudFront-Viewer-City`, and a Lambda@edge viewer request that does the following.

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;
    let body = "";
    let responseStatus = "200";
    if (headers["cloudfront-viewer-city"]) {
        body = headers['cloudfront-viewer-city'][0].value;
    }
    else {
        responseStatus = "500";
        body = "";
    }
    const response = {
        status: responseStatus,
        statusDescription: 'OK',
        headers: {
            'content-type': [{
                    key: 'Content-Type',
                    value: 'application/json'
                }],
            'access-control-allow-origin': [{
                    key: "access-control-allow-origin",
                    value: "*"
                }]
        },
        body: makeBody(body)
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
function makeBody(city) {
    let obj = {
        city: city,
    };
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

The actual result is that the server's IP address gets the lookup, not the forwarded IP.